# PostGIS issue with ST_Clip?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, clip, postgis-raster

I'm trying to clip a raster using a polygon but I end up with a result that doesn't seem right and where some raster pixels are outside the polygon used for the clip.

See image below where polygon is the green outline and each pixels centroid is red:

[image: Polygon is shown as green, raster is greyscale and pixel centroids are red]

I'm using the following SQL statement:

```
select st_union(st_clip(a.rast,b.geom, true))
from temp_jonyp2.dhm a,
    (
    select wkb_geometry geom 
    from i.gdk_bygning 
    where id=347910
    ) b
where st_intersects(a.rast,b.geom)
```

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6 and PostGIS 2.4.

Output of postgis_full_version is:

```
POSTGIS="2.4.0 r15853" PGSQL="96" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.4, released 2016/01/25" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11" RASTER
```

This question might relate to [PostGIS polygon clip inaccurate using ST_Clip and ST_Union from tiled raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159828), but I can't figure out if the issue has been resolved for the version of PostGIS I'm running.

How do I clip a raster with a polygon so that only pixels inside the polygon are included?

UPDATE:
From Vince's suggestion in the comments I tried with a negative buffer. This did shave of the pixels touching the polygon in the areas where the clip looks right, but didn't help with the "wrong" parts. 
See image:
[image: With negative buffer]

Comment: Did you check your projection for both inputs and if needed, did you reproject and try to rerun this clip?

Comment: Have you tried using `ST_Within` in lieu of `ST_Intersects`?

Comment: Both raster and polygon is EPSG 25832

Comment: Haven’t tried with st_within but does this function utilize index?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=does+st_winthin+use+spatial+index+postgis

Comment: So ST_Within doesn’t work with raster and I don’t want to cast to geometry as I guess it’ll be very slow

Comment: Hmm. I imported the raster with 10x10 tiles and registered them as ‘out-of-dB’. Could this be related to the 10x10 tiling? Very speculative I guess:-)

Comment: You have exactly two alternatives for what to do with the pixels which are only touched by the clipping vectors: either to take the partial pixels into the selectíon or to leave them out. The developer has decided to include them. I would do the same. If you want to avoid that I suggest to make the clipping area a bit smaller with negative buffer.

Comment: The problem is that most of the pixels outside the polygon doesn’t touch (pixels are 0.4x0.4meters and the polygon is ten’s of meters on the sides)

Comment: Ah, I understand, you mean the big blocks. I thought that they come from some other raster. My comment is useless, sorry,

Comment: @Vince I see now that ST_Within has a raster version, which I didn't initially find.
But it's very slow and therefore not an option - this should of course should have been part of the question.
To me it seems that ST_Intersects is returning the wrong result.

Comment: ST_Intersects seems to be returning pixels where the centroid intersects.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto The thing is that many pixels are completely outside the polygon so in these cases the centroid can’t be intersecting with the polygon

Comment: It does work fine for me returning those pixels that intersect the centroid (postgis_version 2.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1). So my query is just: select ST_Union(ST_Clip(r.rast, g.geom)
from raster r
join vector g on st_intersects(r.rast, g.geom)

Comment: Try performing a negative buffer of the search shape by the pixel size divided by square root of two -- That should leave off the centroids of edge pixels ( possibly some others).

Comment: @Vince This shaves of the some of the pixels where the polygon actually follows the pixel-outline, but for the areas where the pixels are clearly outside the polygon it has no effect.
https://imgur.com/jQGBKC4